# How to include factor levels when they are missing in some replicas in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, missing-data

I have a dataframe `df` in which I have data about percentages (`df$Percentage`) of different habitats(`df$Habitat`) for specific tracks (`df$Replica`) in different sites (`df$Site`). As an example:

```
df <- data.frame(Site = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
                 Replica = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2),
                 Habitat = c("X","Y","Z","X","Y","X","Y","M","X","M","Z"),
                 Porcentage = c(46,38,16,40,60,20,60,20,35,55,10))
df

   Site Replica Habitat Porcentage
1     A       1       X         46
2     A       1       Y         38
3     A       1       Z         16
4     A       2       X         40
5     A       2       Y         60
6     B       1       X         20
7     B       1       Y         60
8     B       1       M         20
9     B       2       X         35
10    B       2       M         55
11    B       2       Z         10
```

Here, for example, the percentage of habitat `X` at site `A` is 46, while there is no habitat `M` (which is present in site `B`). The sum of all values for a specific `Replica` within a site is `100`. For example, in site `A`, for `Replica == 2`, habitat `X` and `Y` sum 100, which means there is no other habitat present in this replica/track.

I want to calculate both the mean percentage (`Mean_Percentage`) of each habitat per `Site` and the standard error (SE) of the mean. The mean is calculated using `Replica`, since for each `Site` I have repeated measures (= `Replica`).

```
df %>% group_by(Site,Habitat) %>% summarise(Mean_Porcentage = mean(Porcentage),SE = sd(Porcentage)/sqrt(length(Porcentage)))

# A tibble: 7 × 4
# Groups:   Site [2]
  Site  Habitat Mean_Porcentage    SE
  <chr> <chr>             <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     X                  43     3  
2 A     Y                  49    11  
3 A     Z                  16    NA  
4 B     M                  37.5  17.5
5 B     X                  27.5   7.5
6 B     Y                  60    NA  
7 B     Z                  10    NA
```

The problem is that `Mean_Porcentage` and thus, `SE` are not calculated properly. For example, habitat `Z` is present in `Replica == 1` (=16%) but not in `Replica == 2` (=0%) in site `A`. Thus, the mean percentage (`Mean_Porcentage`) of `Z` in site `A` should be `8` (=[16%+0%]/2) and SE should be `8`. Also, habitat `M` is not present in site `A` but it is in site `B`, so I want habitat `M` to appear for site `A` with a `Mean_Percentage` of `0`.

My desired result should be a dataframe as this:

```
df2
  Site Habitat Mean_Porcentage     SE
1    A       M             0.0      0
2    A       X            43.0      3
3    A       Y            49.0     11
4    A       Z             8.0      8
5    B       M            37.5   17.5
6    B       X            27.5    7.5
7    B       Y            30.0     30
8    B       Z             5.0      5
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `xtabs` and `proportions`.

```
proportions(xtabs(Porcentage ~ Site + Habitat, df), 1) * 100
#    Habitat
#Site    M    X    Y    Z
#   A  0.0 43.0 49.0  8.0
#   B 37.5 27.5 30.0  5.0

as.data.frame(proportions(xtabs(Porcentage ~ Site + Habitat, df), 1) * 100)
#  Site Habitat Freq
#1    A       M  0.0
#2    B       M 37.5
#3    A       X 43.0
#4    B       X 27.5
#5    A       Y 49.0
#6    B       Y 30.0
#7    A       Z  8.0
#8    B       Z  5.0
```

Adding the se as described in the question.

```
x <- as.data.frame(proportions(xtabs(Porcentage ~ Site + Habitat, df), 1) * 100)
x <- merge(x, aggregate(cbind(SE = Porcentage) ~ Site + Habitat, df, \(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))), all.x=TRUE)
i <- is.na(x$SE)
x$SE[i] <- x$Freq[i]
x
#  Site Habitat Freq   SE
#1    A       M  0.0  0.0
#2    A       X 43.0  3.0
#3    A       Y 49.0 11.0
#4    A       Z  8.0  8.0
#5    B       M 37.5 17.5
#6    B       X 27.5  7.5
#7    B       Y 30.0 30.0
#8    B       Z  5.0  5.0
```

Comment: Thaks @GKi. One doubt, how coul I inlude standard error (SE) using `xtabs`? I did not include this question just to do not increase complexity. I calculate standard error as `sd(Mean)/sqrt(length(Mean))`. It would be great if I can add SE as a new column...

Comment: I think this is only possible where there are some observations, e.g. with `aggregate(Porcentage ~ Site + Habitat, df, \(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)))`. Which could be add to the other table e.g. by using `merge`.

Comment: I want the SE of the Mean, and the mean is per `Site` and `Habitat`...

Comment: Can you update the Question. Describe what should be calculated and give an expected result.

Comment: All right. I will do it